# How to present a UITableView and its Detail View in the same View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ipad, detailsview

I'd like to show in an iPad application an UITableView and the result of clicking on Cell in the same View. I'm able to show one of them, but not both at the same time. Here's the design idea:

[image: Screen design]

So when I click a cell, the chart will change.

Thanks in advance, everything is welcome!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UITableView` can be used as a subview attached to any `UIViewController`, so this shouldn't be a problem.  You will need to make your view controller handle the data source and delegate methods, as well as the detail view and any other elements.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the solution and I've tried it without succes. I tried: implement 2 new viewcontrollers (one for tableview, other for the charts) and linking them to my UIViewController where I want to show them, and adding this 2 viewcontrollers in the .xib, but no succes. How con I manage that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please help me with this, I don't know how to achieve what I want. I understand TableView behaviour, but not being in the same place. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You only need one view controller.  Drop the tableview onto your nib for the view controller, and compose the detail view controller in the same nib.  Make the controller handle the UITableView data source and delegate methods.

Comment: Additional note: it is (now) possible to have multiple UIViewControllers handling one screen; however, for your app where there is tight coupling between the table (master) and detail data, I don't think that will make much difference - apart from a more complex relationship between VCs.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But how I link the TableView and the Detail in the same ViewController? That's where I get lost. Thanks again.

Comment: I am inclined to say you just do it :-).  Put the chart in the same nib, and the code to control it in your VC.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be accomplish by using a UISplitViewController.

You can also take a look at the "Master Detail Application" Template provided by apple.

Comment: Yes, but I'm already using a splitViewcontroller. I'm trying to show the TableView and its Detail in a DetailView of a SplitViewController. That's why I'm asking :)